# Name of C# program behavior with circular-like assignment

Tags: c#

The code below compiles, but I don't understand the behavior of keeping the 1 element array instead of assigning the two element array. Is there a name for this behavior so that I could search for more information about it? I realize that this code isn't sensible because the 2 byte array could be assigned in the call to the constructor in GetData.

```
using System;

public class Item
{
    public Item(string name, byte[] data)
    {
        Name = name;
        Data = data;
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public byte[] Data { get; set; }
}

public class Test
{
    Item member;

    public Test()
    {
        member = new Item("name0", new byte[1]);
    }
    public static void Main()
    {
        Test test = new Test();

        test.member.Data = test.GetData();

        Console.WriteLine("name={0} array={1}", test.member.Name, test.member.Data.Length);
    }

    public byte[] GetData()
    {
        member = new Item("name1", new byte[1]);

        return new byte[2];  
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no recursion here. Looks more like the programmer was playing around with ideas and left the code in this bad state. I wouldn't try learning anything from it.

Comment: Are you saying that the output is "name=name1 array=1" when you're expecting "name=name1 array=2"?

Comment: What is your intent and your goal here ?

Comment: I was expecting name=name1 array=2 and got name=name1 array=1. It was a bit of playing around.

Comment: Thanks Courtney for clarifying the intent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what's happening:

1. In `new Test()`, a new Item (let's call it object a) is created in the constructor
2. `test.member` is evaluated.  This will return object a.
3. `test.GetMember()` is called, in which:

   1. `member` is re-assigned a new Item object (we'll call it object b)
   2. A byte array of length 2 is returned
4. The Data property of the object retrieved at step #2 (object a) is assigned the two-byte array.
5. Now, when referencing test.member.Data, `test.member` has a reference to object b (due to step 3.1)

This can appear confusing.  As far as naming this behavior, it's all just the evaluation order of statements.  The programming technique to avoid this is to not cause side effects in your "Get" methods; get methods should only return values, not change the data of the object.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate your effort.

Answer (score 0):

The `new byte[0]` is just a placeholder.  You're not actually doing anything with it.  You could just as well assign `null` there, because when you `GetData()`, a `new byte[2]` is assigned to `test.member.data` anyway, and the original `new byte[0]` is garbage collected.

I'm not sure this does anything useful.

Comment: I will try to change that to avoid confusion. The problem with my understanding was that the new byte[2] did not get assigned. The new byte[1] was kept.